# electronic signature mac os x

Tags: cocoa, macos, osx-leopard

I am developing a Cocoa/Objective-C application. I need to use an external device to acquire handwritten signatures in electronic form (e.g. http://www.signotec.com/internet/page.php?naviID=900000169&site=900000168&typ=2&rubrik=900000003&s_sprache=en).

I did not find any Mac OS X compatible device. Does anyone know any solution for this?

Comment: I’m not sure why this question is getting close-because-it-is-not-a-real-question votes. AFAICT, the OP wants to know if there’s a solution to acquire electronic signatures from a device and a corresponding API to request a signature and obtain its representation. Maybe the OP could give a more detailed description of the requirements.

Comment: @Bavarious: Presumably because it's horribly unclear. The only common use of *"electronic signature"* signature that I'm familiar with is a application of cryptographic hashing. I'm guessing the OP wants to be able to uniquely identify the hardware he's running on, but it's a problem that I have to guess. @Radu: Could you be more specific?

Comment: “Not a real question” gets way overused for unclear questions, in my opinion, which is that a question should only be closed if it is worthless and cannot be edited to have worth. This question is certainly salvageable, but only if, @Radu, you provide more specifics about what you want to do.

Comment: @dmckee Cryptographic signatures are normally called _digital signatures_, which is why I’ve read the question as an external device to acquire handwritten signatures in electronic form.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. @Bavarious is right, I was refering to an external device to acquire handwritten signatures. (e.g. http://www.signotec.com/internet/page.php?site=900000168&typ=2&s_sprache=en)

Comment: @Radu Edit your question and provide as much information as you can.

Comment: I've voted to reopen, but at this point, @Radu, you might be better off rolling back your edit and posting a new question with the more specific text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.topazsystems.com makes a signature pad that has linux / solaris libraries, could probably be made to work.

but your are right in that there aren't very many options for a plug-and-play signature HID.

Comment: A company I worked for is using Topaz tablets. Make sure you do your research, there is a browser based way of collecting the signature, but it uses activeX (only available in IE). The decryption tool can be installed on linux, but the signature pad itself requires IE